# spyder Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: anaconda, spyder

On the Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to use spyder as my IDE.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/bin/spyder", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
*ImportError:/home/pearlman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numexpr/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)*
```

when i was try to solve this problem  by running `conda update libgcc`.

After this is completed, when I run `spyder`, I get a Segmentation Fault. Does anyone have any ideas what the issue might be here?

Comment: It seems you're mixing system packages along with Anaconda ones. Do you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set?

Comment: maybe ，I reinstall the ubuntu system so the problem was sloved. thank you very much

Comment: from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /home/pu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libgsttag-1.0.so.0:undefined`symbol:gst_make_element_message_details
 After that ,when I run spyder, Does anyone have any ideas what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem by the following steps. Hope it helps

sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= spyder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

source ~/.bashrc